# await Windows.Media.Brush InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a method, that saves a lot of settings in a configuration file. I create a async method, with the following content:

```
private void SaveStatusBarSettings(Configuration config)
{
  WriteValueToSetting(config, "StatusBarInactiveBackgroundColor", EnvironmentContainer.ConvertMediaBrushToDrawingColor(CurrentSettings.ColorSettings.StatusBarInactiveBackgroundColor).ToHexString());
}
```

In certain circumstances it pops up a InvalidOperationException, that the brush object is in possession of another thread. I read, that the GDI+ is not thread safe and that the problem is the Brush object. Any suggestions, how can I fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is async in this method?

Comment: This method is called by public async Task SaveSettingsAsync(CancellationTokenSource cts)

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way to solve that is with the following utility method (untested):

```
public static Task<tResult> onGuiThread<tResult>( Func<tResult> func )
{
    var disp = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
    if( disp.CheckAccess() )
        return Task.FromResult( func() );

    TaskCompletionSource<tResult> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<tResult>();
    Action act = () =>
    {
        try
        {
            tcs.SetResult( func() );
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            tcs.SetException( ex );
        }
    };
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( act );
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Usage example:

```
string colorString = await onGuiThread(() => 
    EnvironmentContainer.ConvertMediaBrushToDrawingColor( 
        CurrentSettings.ColorSettings.StatusBarInactiveBackgroundColor )
        .ToHexString() )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but this does not solve my problem. The same issue like before.

Comment: @simmeone If your app is windows forms not WPF, you’ll need to replace Dispatcher.BeginInvoke with Control.BeginInvoke, using some control or form that runs on the same thread that uses your StatusBarInactiveBackgroundColor.

Comment: It's a WPF application. Something went wrong on my Code. I have to investicate it more in detail.